# replace strings with certain format in bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed, fread

I have a file like this. it is a 7-column tab file with separator of one space (`sep=" "`).

however, in the 4th column, it is a string with some words which also contains spaces. Then last 3 column are numbers.

test_find.txt

```
A UTR3 0.760 Sterile alpha motif domain|Sterile alpha motif domain;Sterile alpha motif domain . . 0.0007
G intergenic 0.673 BTB/POZ domain|BTB/POZ domain|BTB/POZ domain . . 0.0015
```

I want to replace **space** into **underscore** (e.g. replace "Sterile alpha motif domain" to "Sterile_alpha_motif_domain"). Firstly, find the pattern starting with letters and end with "|", then treat as one string and replace all spaces to "_". Then move to next line and find next patter. (Is there any easier way to do it?)

I was able to use `sed -i -e 's/Sterile alpha motif domain/Sterile_alpha_motif_domain/g' test_find.txt` to only first row, but **cannot generalize it**.

I tried to find all patterns using `sed -n 's/^[^[a-z]]*{\(.*\)\\[^\|]*$/\1/p' test_find.txt` but doesn't work.

can anyone help me?

I want output like this:

```
A UTR3 0.760 Sterile_alpha_motif_domain|Sterile_alpha_motif_domain;Sterile_alpha_motif_domain . . 0.0007
G intergenic 0.673 BTB/POZ_domain|BTB/POZ_domain . . 0.0015
```

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2):

We'll need to two-step processing: first extract the 4th column which may
contain spaces; next replace the spaces in the 4th column with underscores.

With `GNU awk`:

```
gawk '{
    if (match($0, /^(([^ ]+ ){3})(.+)(( [0-9.]+){3})$/, a)) {
        gsub(/ /, "_", a[3])
        print a[1] a[3] a[4]
    }
}' test_find.txt
```

Output:

```
A UTR3 0.760 Sterile_alpha_motif_domain|Sterile_alpha_motif_domain;Sterile_alpha_motif_domain . . 0.0007
G intergenic 0.673 BTB/POZ_domain|BTB/POZ_domain|BTB/POZ_domain . . 0.0015
```

- The regex `^(([^ ]+ ){3})(.+)(( [0-9.]+){3})$` matches a line capturing
  each submatches.
- The 3rd argument (GNU awk extension) `a` is an array name which is
  assigned to the capture group. a[1] holds 1st-3rd columns,
  a[3] holds 4th column, and a[4] holds 5th-7th columns.
- The `gsub` function replaces whitespaces with an underscores.
- Then the columns are concatenated and printed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have special character at the end before the final column with integers, You can try this `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's~([[:alpha:]/]+) ~\1_~g;s/_([[:punct:]])/ \1/g' input_file
0.760 Sterile_alpha_motif_domain|Sterile_alpha_motif_domain;Sterile_alpha_motif_domain . . 0.0007
0.673 BTB/POZ_domain|BTB/POZ_domain|BTB/POZ_domain . . 0.0015
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your promote answer! actually I do have other columns which contains letters. But I do know this column is the only one that contains especial character. Please also see revised sample data.

Comment: also, there is no special characters at the end. it ends with a word. the 2 dots are missing values of 2 columns which supposed to have integers

Comment: So what does the last column and the columnn before that look like? Can you provide a sample @lxcfuji

Answer (score 0):

Without making any assumptions on the content of each field, you can 'brute force' the expected result by counting the number of characters in each field (+ the number of field separators) for the beginning of the line and the end of the line, and use this to manipulate the '4th column', e.g.

```
awk '{start=length($1)+length($2)+length($3)+4; end=length($0)-length($NF)-length($(NF-1))-length($(NF-2))-length($1)-length($2)-length($3)-6; text=substr($0, start, end); gsub(" ", "_", text); print $1, $2, $3, text, $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}' test.txt
```

'Neat' version:

```
awk '{
    start=length($1)+length($2)+length($3)+4
    end=length($0)-length($NF)-length($(NF-1))-length($(NF-2))-length($1)-length($2)-length($3)-6
    text=substr($0, start, end)
    gsub(" ", "_", text)
    print $1, $2, $3, text, $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF
}' test.txt
A UTR3 0.760 Sterile_alpha_motif_domain|Sterile_alpha_motif_domain;Sterile_alpha_motif_domain . . 0.0007
G intergenic 0.673 BTB/POZ_domain|BTB/POZ_domain|BTB/POZ_domain . . 0.0015
```

Breakdown:

```
awk '{
# How many characters are there before column 4 begins (length of each field + total count of field separators (in this case, "4"))
start=length($1)+length($2)+length($3)+4;
# How many characters are there in column 4 (total - (first 3 fields + last 3 fields + total field separators (6)))
end=length($0)-length($NF)-length($(NF-1))-length($(NF-2))-length($1)-length($2)-length($3)-6;
# Use the substr function to define column 4
text=substr($0, start, end);
# Substitute spaces for underscores in column 4
gsub(" ", "_", text);
# Print everything
print $1, $2, $3, text, $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF
}' test.txt
```